# Prove: One and only one congruent chord intersects a given chord at a given point

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, power-of-the-point

Consider circle $\bigcirc O$ with chord $AB$ which is not a diameter.  Let $P$ be a point on $AB$ which is not the midpoint.  Clearly there exists a chord $CD$ which is congruent to $AB$ and intersects it at $P$.  (Proof: Reflect $A$ over diameter $PO$ to find $C$ and $B$ over $PO$ to find $D$.)

I believe this chord $CD$ is unique, but can't find a simple proof of it.  Below is my (complicated) proof.  **What is a simple way to prove uniqueness of $CD$?**

---

Assume WLOG $$AP < PB \\ CP \leq PD.$$  By Power of Point $P$, we have $$AP \cdot PB = CP \cdot PD.$$  If $$AP + PB = CP + PD$$ then $AP \cong CP$ as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4825276/if-two-pairs-of-numbers-have-equal-sums-and-products-what-can-we-conclude-about/4825286#4825286).

By Euclid's III.7, there is only one point $C$ on the circle such that $C \neq A$ and $AP \cong CP$.  This completes the proof, but seems needlessly complicated*.  Is there a simpler proof?

***Why?** The claim seems to be a simple observation necessitated by symmetry (or perhaps also noting that segment length is a monotonic function of chord angle, [III.7](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookIII/propIII7.html)).  Instead, I had to use the full power of the PoP theorem, combined with quadratic algebra (needed to show $ab=cd, a+b=c=d \implies \{ a,b \} = \{ c,d \}$).  That's simply too much machinery for a simple observation.

Comment: Your proof is how I would have approached this. What seems complicated about it? IE Are you asking why "intersection of 2 circles with distinct radius and common overlap is 2 points"?  $\quad$ Another approach could be to calculate how a rotation of $ AB$ by $ \theta$ to $C^*D^*$ results in the intersection $P^*$, and showing that is a mono variant on $AB$. However that involves slogging through a bunch of uninspired trigo.

Comment: @CalvinLin Your observation that the claim is equivalent to "intersection of 2 circles with distinct radius and common overlap is 2 points"[III.10](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookIII/propIII10.html) is intriguing and may be exactly what I'm looking for.  Do you care to expand it to an answer?

Comment: That doesn't help resolve your "don't want to use quadratic algebra". IE I'm starting off with $ A P = CP$, and drawing a circle of radius $AP$ about $P$, to show that there is a unique other point $C$.   $\quad$ And also bear in mind, that essentially is using quadratic algebra (at least when we look at the intersection of 2 circles in coordinate form). There might be other ways to hide that math.